# Understanding a small groovy script

Tags: groovy

I am absolutely new to groovy and I am trying to understand an existing groovy code to make changes. The code is a small groovy script like so:

```
package myapp.confg

appName = "myapp"
appVersion = "103"

tags {
    ags = "${myapp}"
}
```

I understand that `appName` and `appVersion` are global variables. However I cannot understand what `tags` is. Its not a closure and its not a map. Any ideas what this may be? Is it some way of creating a named scope? How can I access the value of `ags` from outside the `tags` scope?

Comment: It could ba a function with closure as a parameter. But without execution context it's just a guess.

Comment: It must be a closure, because {} is only used for closures and blocks for the keyword-y things like if/for/while/...

Comment: This is some sort of DSL and without the environment this script is run there is no way to give you proper advice.

Comment: @cfrick thanks I agree that there is a large framework from where it is called. Unfortunately I cannot put all that code here. I will investigate this and perhaps add comment as to what this was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a method with a Closure in the last parameter, and this is very common in Groovy to use the last parameter in a method as a `Closure`, this comes very handy to build a DSL (Delegation...) like so:

```
// Example 1
def t(Closure c){
  println('from Closure')
}

t {
  // do something
}

// Example 2
def t2(int i, int j, Closure c){
  print("closure with: $i, $j")
}

t2(1,2) {
  // do other something
}
```

More examples can be found in the [doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html#section-delegatesto) for Delegation.

Comment: thanks this is what it turned out to be. This is an invocation of a method with a `Closure` argument.